# DB::raw not using model connection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a count of model rows from a different database. I have both databases configured fine. My problem is that it doesn't seem to be using the same connection when attempting to perform raw queries.

Code:

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'infused2';
    public $timestamps = false;

    function campaignCount(Campaign $campaign)
    {
        $leads = $this->join('lead_history', 'leads.id', '=', 'lead_history.id_lead')->join('assignments', 'leads.id', '=', 'assignments.id_lead');

        if (!empty($campaign->lead_date_created_operand)) {
            if ($campaign->leadDateCreatedOperand->name == 'day age') {
                $leads->where(DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(lead_history.date_created), '%d-%m-%Y') = date_format(".strtotime($campaign->lead_date_created_value).", '%d-%m-%Y')"));
            }
            else if ($campaign->leadDateCreatedOperand->name == 'month age') {
                $leads->where(DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(lead_history.date_created), '%m-%Y') = date_format(".strtotime($campaign->lead_date_created_value).", '%m-%Y')"));
            }
        }

        if (!empty($campaign->lead_date_assigned_operand)) {
            if ($campaign->leadDateAssignedOperand->name == 'day age') {
                $leads->where(DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(assignments.date_assigned), '%d-%m-%Y') = date_format(".strtotime($campaign->lead_date_assigned_value).", '%d-%m-%Y')"));
            }
            else if ($campaign->leadDateAssignedOperand->name == 'month age') {
                $leads->where(DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(assignments.date_assigned), '%m-%Y') = date_format(".strtotime($campaign->lead_date_assigned_value).", '%m-%Y')"));
            }
        }

        return $leads->count();
    }
}
```

I am getting error `Database [mysql] not configured`. Why is this happening and how do I make the raw queries use the model connection?

Comment: On your app/config/database.php, do you have an 'infused2' under connections? You would probably have infused1 and infused2.

Comment: Yes I do have it setup in the database config.

Comment: Is Campaign also a Model? If so, does it reside in another database? If the answer is yes, do you also have a protected $connection = 'db_name' for Campaign?

Comment: Campaign is also a model and campaign has its connection parameter specified.

Comment: Go to your console and type this(without quotation marks): "php artisan tinker". Then type this: "test = DB::connection('infused1')->getPdo();" Do you see an uptime? If the answer is yes, do the same for infused2. Does it also show an uptime?

Comment: I figured it out using the query builder and answered.

Comment: why do You use DB::raw , You can simply use whereRaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

```
    $query = DB::connection($this->connection)->table($this->getTable());

    if (!empty($campaign->lead_date_created_operand)) {
        $query->join('lead_history', 'lead_history.id_lead', '=', 'leads.id');

        if ($campaign->leadDateCreatedOperand->name == 'day age') {
            $query->whereRaw("date_format(from_unixtime(lead_history.date_created), '%d-%m-%Y') = date_format(from_unixtime(".strtotime('-'.$campaign->lead_date_created_value)."), '%d-%m-%Y')");
        }
        else if ($campaign->leadDateCreatedOperand->name == 'month age') {
            $query->whereRaw("date_format(from_unixtime(lead_history.date_created), '%m-%Y') = date_format(from_unixtime(".strtotime('-'.$campaign->lead_date_created_value)."), '%m-%Y')");
        }
    }

    if (!empty($campaign->lead_date_assigned_operand)) {
        $query->join('assignments', 'assignments.id_lead', '=', 'leads.id');

        if ($campaign->leadDateAssignedOperand->name == 'day age') {
            $query->whereRaw("date_format(from_unixtime(assignments.date_assigned), '%d-%m-%Y') = date_format(from_unixtime(".strtotime('-'.$campaign->lead_date_assigned_value)."), '%d-%m-%Y')");
        }
        else if ($campaign->leadDateAssignedOperand->name == 'month age') {
            $query->whereRaw("date_format(from_unixtime(assignments.date_assigned), '%m-%Y') = date_format(from_unixtime(".strtotime('-'.$campaign->lead_date_assigned_value)."), '%m-%Y')");
        }
    }

    return $query->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration you may need to do

```
DB::connection('infused2')...
```